# dotnet 6 Preview 7 - Error using dotnet watch run

Tags: .net-core, frameworks, preview, watch, dot

I'm getting an error when attempting to use dotnet watch run from within a powershell console in Visual Studio 2022. I just create a Blazor Server site from the template and no changes went straight to powershell.

```
It was not possible to find any compatible framework version The framework 'Microsoft.NETCore.App', version '6.0.0-preview.7.21377.19' was not found.
  - The following frameworks were found:
      6.0.0-preview.6.21352.12 at [C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Preview\dotnet\runtime\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
```

I've installed all appropriate runtimes and SDKs.

Answer (score 0):

Struggled with this until I noticed the directory being used for the dotnet start was C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Preview\dotnet\runtime\shared.

Within there was Microsoft.NETCore.App directory which was missing 6.0.0-preview.7.21377.19.

I copied the directory from C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App into there.

Running again produced

```
It was not possible to find any compatible framework version
The framework 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.App', version '6.0.0-preview.7.21378.6' was not found.
  - No frameworks were found.
```

I checked C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Preview\dotnet\runtime\shared and it was missing Microsoft.AspNetCore.App.

I created that directory manually.

Copied 6.0.0-preview.7.21378.6 from C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App into that directory.

Everything then worked.